# I'm try use a Simple Switch case but its not working?

Tags: c

I want it assign a string value for each case and also be able to print and do i require a pointer if yes why

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    char d;
    printf("Input a Number\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    switch(a)
    {
    case 1:
        d='One';
    case 2:
        d='Two';
    case 3:
        d='Three';
    }

    printf("You entered %s",d);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output:

```
input a number
1

you entered one
```

Comment: Missing breaks.

Comment: But when asking questions you need to explain what *is* happening as well, e.g., "it always prints 'three'".

Comment: Also, you're trying to stuff a lot of characters into a single character. A tutorial might be a better place to start.

Comment: Please look here for the proper syntax: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-statement-cc/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

1. missing `#include <stdio.h>`
2. assigning "strings" between ' ' to a char
3. missing `break` statements. Without `break` the flow ofn the program simply continues to the next `case`.
4. Not really wrong but poor style: you should name your variables with meaningful names.

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number;
    const char *numbername;  // const is not mandatory
    printf("Input a Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    switch (number)
    {
    case 1:
        numbername = "One";
        break;
    case 2:
        numbername = "Two";
        break;
    case 3:
        numbername = "Three";
        break;
    }

    printf("You entered %s", numbername);
    return 0;
}
```

Be aware that there no such thing as a "string" type in C. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your beginner's C text book.

Forget the `const` keyword for the moment, this is a more advanced topic.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you have is not with the case statement: your problem is that a string literals are surrounded by **double quotes** (`"`), and never by apostrophes (`'`), as they are reserved for character literals.

What seems strange is that you have used double quotes in the `printf()` call below.

Note: the program should have complaint about that, so you have not gotten an executable program.  Please, don't just say *This doesn't work* as every question posted here is related to something that just *doesn't work.*